# Is $h$ and homeomorphis of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ on itself?

Tags: general-topology

I have the following problem:

> Given the sequences $(a_1, a_2, ...)$ and $(b_1,b_2,...)$ of real numbers with $a_i>0$ for all $i$, define $h:\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ by the equation.
>   $$h((x_1,x_2, x_3,...))=(a_1 x_1+b_1, a_2x_2+b_2, a_3x_3+b_3,...) $$
>   If $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ have the box topology. What kind of function this define?

Is easy to see that $g((x_1,x_2, x_3,...))=\left(\displaystyle\frac{x_1-b_1}{a_1}, \displaystyle\frac{x_2-b_2}{a_2}, \displaystyle\frac{x_1-b_3}{a_3},...\right) $ is the inverse. Then $h$ is biyective.

In the case $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ have the product topology we can prove using the universal propierty for product topology that $h$ is an homeomorphism.

I would like a hint to know what kind of function $h$ is if we consider the bos topology.

Thanks!

Comment: You really just need continuity of $h$, since the general form would also prove that $g$ is continuous, since $g(\bar x)=(c_ix_i+d_i)_i$, with $c_i=a_i^{-1}$ and $d_i=-b_ia_i^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a homeomorphism, because $h$ and $h^{-1}$ is continuous.

Write $h_i(x)=a_ix+b_i$ and $g_i(x)=a_i^{-1}x -b_ia_i^{-1}$. The basis elements of the box topology are sets of the form $U=\prod (y_i,z_i)$. But since $g_i$ is strictly increasing, it is pretty obvious that:

$$h^{-1}(U) = \prod_i (g_i(y_i),g_i(z_i))$$

That is, $h^{-1}$ of a box is another box. $h$ is continuous.

More generally, assume $X_i$ is an indexed set of topologies and $X=\prod X_i$  is given the product topology. If $h_i:X_i\to X_i$ is a sequence of homeomorphisms, then $h:X\to X$ defined as:

$$h((x_1,x_2,\dots) = (h_1(x_1),h_2(x_2),\dots,)$$

is a homeomorphism, because it has an inverse of the same form (the $i$th component only depends on the $i$th input,) and $h$ and the inverse send products of open sets to products of open sets.

Comment: Then ¿$h$ is indeed an homeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, it is a homeomorphism, because $h$ and $h^{-1}$ are continuous.